Class Component to Functional Component aggrid customcell editor
I am trying to change my class component to functional component. But the result is different. This is a aggrid customcellrenderer
[  { 
headerName: "Status",     
field: "active",     
tooltipField: "status",     
headerTooltip: "Status",     
cellRenderer: "controlsCellRenderer",     
cellEditor: ToggleSwitch,     
menuTabs: []   } ]

ClassComponent
export default class test extends Component { state = { showActions: false };

handleEdit = () => {this.setState(
  {
    showActions: true
  },
  () => this.api.setRowData(this.state.rows)
);};

ControlsGroup = ({ node }) => 
{ console.log(this.state.showActions); // return true (which is what i want)
return (
  <Form.Check
    type="switch"
    id={`{node.id}`}
    label={node.data.active ? "Active" : "Inactive"}
    checked={node.data.active}
    disabled={!this.state.showActions}
  />
);
};

}`

Functional component
function test({
  //props
}) {
  const [showActions, setShowActions] = useState(false);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(showActions) // return correctly
  }, [showActions]);

  
  const handleEdit = () => {
    setShowActions(true);

  };

  const controlsGroup = ({ node }) => {
    console.log(showActions); // return false should return true
    

    return (
      <Form.Check
        type="switch"
        id={`${node.id}`}
        label={node.data.active ? "Active" : "Inactive"}
        checked={node.data.active}
        disabled={!showActions}
      />
    );
  };
  }

I want to know why after i change to functional component the showActions is not being updated any more. What other way can i do? i tried using usecallback but it is also not working

Where and when do you call handleEdit? it's not in the code you shared.

What does this have to do with functional programming? Please at least mouse-hover over the tag and read the description before adding it. I've removed the functional programming tag.

Your code doesn't make any sense. What's supposed to be the functional component, test or controlsGroup? And why aren't they capitalized? And if the FC is supposed to be test why don't you return anything from it? And if the FC is supposed to be controlsGroup why have test at all? How is this code even running to give you the logs? You don't return controlsGroup nor call it inside of test? Please edit this into something that we can run. Also please format your code using something like prettier so somebody besides yourself can read it.
